# How can I blend two textures together using Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, texturing, node-editor

I am trying to put dirty material over a concrete material in  cycles. Now I am trying to do this using a color ramp and a mix shader, but I don't know if this is the only way or best way to do this. How can I mix these two textures together?

My first way:

[image]

The concrete texture and the grunge texture:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use a mix shader with two diffuse and your textures as input.

Comment: If those are the actual sizes of the texture you are using, just on the side note you will want to keep in the power of 2. Example 256 X 256 pixel, 512 X 512 pixel and 1024 X 1024 pixel. You can read up more about it.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33342/how-to-mix-face-textures-across-uv-edges

Comment: If you see an answer that solved your problem, please accept it. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 23):

From your nodes setup, it looks like you're trying to mix the original shader with nothing. While this is technically possible it is not the cleanest way to do things.

You don't actually have to create a new shader and use the mix shader to mix two textures. There is a node called MixRGB which can mix two textures, without creating a new shader each time.

There are a few ways to mix a dirty texture onto another texture. Here are a few:

1. The most basic setup is just a basic mix:
   [image]
2. If you change the mix type you can get a few different effects:

   *Overlay*
   [image]

   *Multiply*
   [image]

   *Darken*
   [image]
3. However, it looks like you want more control over what values are being effected (you're using a color ramp). So you can use the texture as the color ramp *and* as the texture itself (ignore the MixRGB on the bottom. That just makes it blue so it's easier to see):
   [image]

Comment: On the other hand, if you do Mix two different shaders, you can give them different properties (rough concrete, anisotropic grunge, for example).