# Unable to change specific faces color of a cube

Tags: mesh, materials

[image: a selected edge of the cube]

I want to assign a specific color to the faces, but I am unable to do that.
Upon assigning a color through materials, the entire cube turns that color. Please help!

Comment: Welcome. You could assign materias [to different faces](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh) of the mesh, not edges. In order to make cube corners of different colors you could either add extra edges with beveling edges or to paint a mask for mixing 2 colors with material nodes, see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3105/how-can-i-blend-two-textures-together-using-cycles and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2100/1245

Comment: did my answer solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

- First add an empty material slot to your mesh as shown below:

[image]

- Add another slot
- Add new material to the second slot and set it's diffuse color as shown below:

[image]
[image]

- Switch to edit mode and select the face you want then select the material you created and click assign as shown below and that's it.

[image]